# Python - list concatenation with shallow referencing?

Tags: python-3.x, list, concatenation

I'm working on such project, and got question for code compression.

There are many ways for list concatenation `a+b`, `a.extend(b)`, and so on.

but my question is, there are any way for **shallow concatenation** of the lists; for example,

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = [4,5]
c = a+b
c
>> [1,2,3,4,5]
b[0] = 10
c
>> [1,2,3,4,5]
```

but, my desired result is `[1,2,3,10,5]`, then how to define `c` for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you create a nested list from `a` and `b` you can kinda achieve what you are looking for:

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3]
>>> b = [4, 5]
>>> c = [a, b]
>>> b[0] = 10
>>> c
[[1, 2, 3], [10, 5]]
>>> c = [val for sub_list in c for val in sub_list]
>>> c
[1, 2, 3, 10, 5]
```

Comment: Kinda fine approach. Would performance be better than ```a+b``` all the time? thanks!

Comment: Yeah most likely since no copying has to be done since `c` is just using the memory address of the a and b lists.

Answer (score 0):

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = [4,5]
b[0] = 10
c = a+b
print(c)
```

## or

```
import copy
a = [1,2,3]
b = [4,5]
c=[a,b]
bb = copy.copy(c)
c[1][0]=10
print([val for l in c for val in l])
# refer this link for shallow-deep-copy reference 

# https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/shallow-deep-copy
```